# div with smaller list is lower on page - CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to make two divs, each containing a title and a list, next to each other. However, if one list is smaller than the other, then the div with the smaller list is lower on the web page:
[image]

This is the code for the divs:

```
<div id='classes' class="profileList">
    <h2 class="title">Classes</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Soldier</li>
        <li>Sniper</li>
        <li>Spy</li>
    </ul>
</div><div id="divisions" class="profileList">
    <h2 class="title">Divisions</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Steel</li>
        <li>Silver</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(The end of the left one and the start of the right one are right next to each other because otherwise 50% div width does not put the divs next to each other)

This is the CSS:

```
.title {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-shadow: #FAD2AF 0 0 6px;
}

.profileList {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Why are these div tops at different heights when the elements aren't equal? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `.profileList` to this:

```
.profileList {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

when you use `inline-block`, you need to give it the desired vertical align, since the default is `baseline`